# Best way to document method which returns method invocation

Tags: javascript, documentation, jsdoc

Looking on the current example:

```
/**
@param {int} first number
@param {int} second number
@throws ?????
@returns ??????
*/
function sum(numberOne, numberTwo) {
  return sumTwoNumbers(numberOne, numberTwo);
}

/**
@param {int} first number
@param {int} second number
@throws {error} error
@returns {int} number
*/
function sumTwoNumbers(numberOne, numberTwo) {
  if (!Number.isInteger(numberOne)) {
    throw new Error('argument must be integer');
  }
  return numberOne + numberTwo;
}

sum(1, 2);
```

What should contain @throws and @returns comments in function sum

Comment: Is it simple documentation? or are you using any tool to generate doc?

Comment: I'm using jsdoc to generate it, but I'm also interested which is the best approach for this scenario.

Comment: Technically, `sum` doesn't throw anything, and returns an `Number`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First add the documentation for function `sum` saying, this method is *a wrapper*, or *returns the output returned by `sumTwoNumbers` function.*

Copy the same for `throws` and `returns` from sumTwoNumbers function. Finally add the next annotation for `sum` function **[@see](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-see.html)** tag, which points to the `sumTwoNumbers`.

```
@throws error    //if thrown by sumTwoNumbers
@returns number
@see {@link sumTwoNumbers}
```